# Why is self-sufficiency considered by Aristotle to be an important characteristic of a city-state?

Tags: aristotle, political-philosophy

In *Politics*, Book I, Aristotle wrote

> A complete community constituted out of several villages, once it
> reaches the limit of total SELF-SUFFICIENCY, practically speaking, is a city-state.

Why does he seem to emphasize self-sufficiency so much? Can anyone give me some clues (maybe from the perspective of historical background or history of ideas)?

Comment: Consider today's war in Ukraine: how much economic interconnection is strategically relevant.

Answer (score 4):

[An article by Robert Mayhew](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/26215898) (1991) provides a detailed examination of what Aristotle means by self-sufficiency and why it is fundamental to the purpose of the city. If you're imagining that Aristotle sees the city as a walled compound without external trade, this is not the case. Aristotle simply means that the city should have a diverse and prosperous population so that it can meet its basic needs with great efficiency, thereby **allowing enough leisure time for enough people to persue politics and other higher persuits**.